# Running a function depending upon multiple signals

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I have two signals which are NOT necessarily received at the same time.

#### First signal

First signal is emitted by `MyClass` and is handled by a slot of `MyClass`:

```cpp
QObject::connect(this, &MyClass::ready, 
                 this, &MyClass::handleReady);

void MyClass::handleReady()
{
    qDebug() << "Ready to do next step";
}

// ... somewhere in MyClass implementation, signal is emitted:
emit ready();
```

#### Second signal

Second signal is emitted by a member object and is handled by a slot of `MyClass`:

```cpp
QObject::connect(m_member, &MemberClass::enabledChanged, 
                 this,     &MyClass::handleEnabledChange);
//...
void MyClass::handleEnabledChange(const bool enabled)
{
    qDebug() << "Is member enabled?" << enabled;
}
```

---

I intend to run some code (like a function), depending upon two condition:

1. First signal, i.e. `ready` is received
2. Second signal, i.e. `enabledChanged`, is received and its Boolean parameter is `true`

I cannot figure out how to check for satisfaction of above conditions.

### UPDATE

Now my signals count is increased to three. So my code execution depends on three conditions.

Comment: Are the signals always coming in this order or is the order irrelevant?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Signals might be received in any order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a method in MyClass which checks if both conditions are true and call this methiod in both slots. Make the conditions member of myClass

```
bool MyClass::areBothConditionsTrue() {
    if(m_conditionA && m_conditionB)
        return true:
    return false;
}

void MyClass::handleReady()
{
    qDebug() << "Ready to do next step";
    m_conditionA = true;
    bool b = areBothConditionsTrue();
}

void MyClass::handleEnabledChange(const bool enabled)
{
    qDebug() << "Is member enabled?" << enabled;
    m_conditionB = enabled;
    bool b = areBothConditionsTrue();
}
```

The further code does depend on what you want to do with this information

Comment: Thanks =) let me try to implement this approach :)

Answer (score 2):

I do not have reputation enough to comment [RoQuOTriX answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57991262/5880425) so made a separate one.

In case your handlers count will increase, you can create the state object in `MyClass` which stores all conditions by adding extra level of abstraction:

```
void MyClass::handleReady(State& state)
{
    qDebug() << "Ready to do next step";
    state.m_conditionA.setFlag(true);
}
```

...but then you will need to implement the `State` class and `State`'s conditions holder class inherited from `QObject` to emit signal `flagChanged` when `setFlag` is called. Then just `connect(m_conditionA, &Condition::flagChanged, this, &State::checkAllConditions)` and store all conditions in some associative container.

Comment: Actually my handlers count is increased to 3 now! Thanks =)